# Test cases getting skipped with Selenium WebDriver using TestNG framework

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, automated-tests, testng

I am using Selenium `WebDriver` with `TestNG` framework for running test suite on **Windows and MAC** platform on **different browsers - Chrome, IE, firefox and Safari**. I have around **300 test cases** in my test suite.

The problem is that some of the test cases gets skipped in between where I believe driver becomes unresponsive. However the logs failed to capture any details why the test cases are getting skipped.

The `reporter class` extends `TestListenerAdapter` and hence the skipped test cases gets listed in the log file with the use of `onConfigurationSkip` method. It only prints that a particular test case has been skipped.

Below are some code snippets for reference

### Code from Reporter Class

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationSkip(ITestResult testResult) {
    LOGGER.info(String.format("Skipped Configuration for : %s", testResult.getMethod().getMethodName()));
}
```

### Sample Test Class

```
public class TestClass {
private WebDriver driver;

@Parameters({ "platform", "browser"})
@BeforeClass
public void setUp(String platform, String browser) {
    // Creates a new driver instance based on platform and browser details
    driver = WebDriverFactory.getDriver(platform, browser);
    // Login to web application
    Utils.login(driver, username, password);
}


@Test
public void sampleTestMethod() {
   // scripts for validating Web elements
}

@AfterClass
public void tearDown() {
     driver.quit();;
}
}
```

Observations:

- `driver.quit()` doesn't guarantee that driver instance has been closed because I can still see driver instance running in task manager. Again this is intermittent and happens sometimes only.
- This issue is observed on all platform and browser
- This is an intermittent issue and probability of its occurrence increases as the number of test cases increase in test suite
- There is no definite pattern of skipped test cases. The test cases get randomly skipped on some browser and platform
- The probability of occurance of skip test cases increases with subsequent run of test suite. I believe the reason is that more and more driver instances that were not properly closed keep running in the back ground
- Normally a **test Class has 5-15 test methods** and new `driver` instance is created every time in `@BeforeClass` method and is closed in `@AfterClass`

Any Suggestions? Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

If you're fine with opening and closing the browsers around every test then you should use @BeforeMethod or @AfterMethod instead of @BeforeClass and @AfterClass

If you follow the following code and its output then you'll find that @BeforeMethod executes before every test annotated methods however, @BeforeClass does only once for all methods in the class.

Since I don't have your full code to analyze then I can just assume that your tests are trying to reuse the wrong driver instances. So the best bet would be to close it down after every test execution finishes.

**Code:**

package com.autmatika.testng;

import org.testng.annotations.*;

public class FindIt {

```
@BeforeClass
public void beforeClass(){
    System.out.println("Before Class");
}

@AfterClass
public void afterClass(){
    System.out.println("After Class");
}


@BeforeMethod
public void beforeTest(){
    System.out.println("Before Test");
}

@AfterMethod
public void afterTest(){
    System.out.println("After Test");
}

@Test
public void test1(){
    System.out.println("test 1");
}

@Test
public void test2(){
    System.out.println("test 2");
}
@Test
public void test3(){
    System.out.println("test 3");
}
@Test
public void test4(){
    System.out.println("test 4");
}
```

}

**Output:**

```
Before Class
Before Test
test 1
After Test
Before Test
test 2
After Test
Before Test
test 3
After Test
Before Test
test 4
After Test
After Class

===============================================
Default Suite
Total tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

Answer (score 0):

The most common reason for the test cases getting skipped with Selenium using TestNG is if your methods are dependent on other method and a method you depend on is failed.

Comment: Thanks Harish for the response. In this case, all the methods are independent from each other and the error specifically comes in @BeforeClass configuration where a new Driver object is taken and logged in. Seems like the driver fails to initialise a new object.

Comment: As you suspected, it might be the issue with driver not getting closed properly in @AfterClass. Anyways, why do you want to quit driver after every class? You can use existing driver for running test cases instead of quitting and creating an instance of the WebDriver in every class. At the end of your test suite you can quit the driver. Also, you can put a null check in your driver initialization method so that WebDriver instance is created only if not null. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

To get information on why the test got skipped you can implement that in after test method as below :-

```
@AfterMethod
public void afterTest(ItestResult result) {
    Throwable t = result.getThrowable();
    // with the object of t you can get the stacktrace and log it into your reporter
}
```

and to avoid tests getting skipped you can have **alwaysRun** parameter to be true after the @Test annotation

```
@Test(alwaysRun=true)
```

to avoid the webdriver getting retarted do the driver cleanups in methods with @BeforeMethod and @AfterMethod annotations, so try changing the annotation of **setUp** and **tearDown** methods to **@BeforeMethod** and **@AfterMethod** respectively